# How does tweaking work for x-only keys, and what is not good in the example I gave?

Tags: schnorr-signatures, key-tweaking, x-only-pubkeys

How does normal key tweaking work in case of Schnorr digital signature schemes?

For all examples I am using online tool for [point multiplication](https://andrea.corbellini.name/ecc/interactive/modk-mul.html) and [point addition](https://andrea.corbellini.name/ecc/interactive/modk-add.html). (I suggest you to use them if it is easier for you)

Let's consider the following curve (it's same as secp256k1 just smaller - it has 17 points including point of `Inf`):

```
a = 2
b = 4
p = 11
G = (2, 4)
```

Also, let's consider two private keys and it's corresponding public keys:

```
PrivK1 = 7
PrivK2 = 10
PubK1 = 7 * (2, 4) = (3, 9)
PubK2 = 10 * (2, 4) = (3, 2)
```

At the end, let's consider that the tweak is `3` (TW).

In ECDSA, this key tweaking works as I expect and it looks as follow:

```
For the first private key (7) - public key (3, 9) pair:
(1) From the private key side:
PrivK1' = PrivK1 + TW = 7 + 3
PrviK1' = 10
PubK1' = PrivK1' * G = 10 * (2, 4)
PubK1' = (3, 2)
(2) From the public key side:
PubK1' = PubK1 + G + G + G = (3, 9) + (2, 4) + (2, 4) + (2, 4)
PubK1' = (3, 2)

(1) == (2)

For the second private key (10) - public key (3, 2) pair:
(1) From the private key side:
PrivK1' = PrivK1 + TW = 10 + 3
PrviK1' = 13
PubK1' = PrivK1' * G = 13 * (2, 4)
PubK1' = (7, 3)
(2) From the public key side:
PubK1' = PubK1 + G + G + G = (3, 2) + (2, 4) + (2, 4) + (2, 4)
PubK1' = (7, 3)

(1) == (2)
```

For both private key - public key pairs, we got a match.

**However, for the Schnorr it does not match when the private key produce the ODD Y coordinate. That is the case with the first private key - public key pair, take a look:**

```
For the first private key (7) - public key (3, 2) pair:
NOTE: Here the public key is not (3, 9) but (3, 2) since we take always EVEN Y coo
(1) From the private key side:
PrivK1' = PrivK1 + TW = 7 + 3
PrviK1' = 10
PubK1' = PrivK1' * G = 10 * (2, 4)
PubK1' = (3, 2)
(2) From the public key side:
PubK1' = PubK1 + G + G + G = (3, 2) + (2, 4) + (2, 4) + (2, 4)
PubK1' = (7, 3)

(1) != (2)

For the second private key (10) - public key (3, 2) pair:
(1) From the private key side:
PrivK1' = PrivK1 + TW = 10 + 3
PrviK1' = 13
PubK1' = PrivK1' * G = 13 * (2, 4)
PubK1' = (7, 3)
(2) From the public key side:
PubK1' = PubK1 + G + G + G = (3, 2) + (2, 4) + (2, 4) + (2, 4)
PubK1' = (7, 3)

(1) == (2)
```

So, the private key after tweaking does not match the tweaked public key in case of odd Y coordinate, so it will not be able to produce a valid signature.

What am I doing wrong or what did I not understand correctly?

Thanks!!

Comment: I may write a full answer later, but perhaps this lets you solve it yourself: going from odd to even Y coordinate corresponds to implicitly negating the private key. If you tweak after dropping an odd Y coordinate, you need to therefore do the same and subtract the tweak rather than adding it.